# An exception thrown in MYSQL with UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I executed following query:

```
UPDATE transactions SET description='empty' WHERE description='empty' + ''
```

But it results into following exception:

```
Exception details: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Simple Transaction'
```

Following is transactions table structure:

```
userid               int(11)   
transactionId        int(11)    
sum                  int(11)
description          varchar(50)
transactionDate      date
```

Any pointer to resolve this exception.

Comment: Why the `+''` at the end of the statement?

Comment: @Jens I need these empty '' space at end. I'm trying SQLI on the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  UPDATE transactions 
  SET description='empty' 
  WHERE description =  CONCAT ('empty', '')
```

I am not sure why you need to have a empty space at the end.